# How do i limit the range of the x or y value in High charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to limit the range of one of the axis of my chart(lets say a max value of 50), but the data should not be truncated. ie, it should display at the plot for 50, but the tooltip should still contain the real value(ie, 116.6)

```
series: [ {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 116.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
```

A base fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kD6q3/

Comment: Obviosuly you can prepare your translator which will map your real data to "transformed", then use it in the series object. All depends on your logic, and how you set a min/max values (based on what?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in this way,

maintain 2 data sets, one to plot the values and other to show on tooltip.

now manage which value is to be shown from tooltip formatter

data section:

```
realValues = [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 116.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8];
data = [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 50, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
```

tooltip section

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return realValues[this.point.x] + '°C'
    }
},
```

updated your fiddle here for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/kD6q3/1/